# Using Chart.js client-side in Atlasboard

Tags: client-side, chart.js, atlasboard

How can a third-party javascript library be made available for client-side use in Atlasboard? `require` doesn't work in widgets, and I don't want to have to import the whole library into every widget that uses the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Place the javascript library file (such as `Chart.min.js`) in `assets/javascripts/`.
2. In the JSON config for the dashboard(s) which will load the widgets that will rely on the library, add the name of the library to the `layout.customJS` array:

Example:

```
{
  "title": "My Dashboard",
  "titleVisible": false,

  "description": "a neat dashboard",

  "layout": {
    "gridSize" : { "columns" : 20, "rows" : 12 },
    "customJS" : ["Chart.min.js"],
    "widgets" : [
        ...
    ]
  },

  "config": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Nothing special needs to be done in the Widget. You can just use the library:

```
var graph = new Chart(ctx).Radar(data);
```